# Почему запуск двух рабочих сценариев Cucumber вместе заканчивается NullPointer?

Tags: java, test-automation, cucumber

Пишу тесты с помощью Cucumber, вот как выглядит feature-file:

```
# language:ru
Функционал: Фильтр на странице 'Где сейчас'
  Контекст: Чтобы на главной странице отображались или сотрудники или задачи или объекты
  "Диспетчер" должен иметь возможность фильтровать отображение

  Сценарий: выбор фильтра "Сотрудники"
    Пусть я зашёл на главную страницу сервиса
    Если нажимаю на кнопку "Фильтр"
    Тогда появлется всплывающее меню
    Если выбираю фильтр "Сотрудники"
    Тогда отображается список групп сотрудников
    И на карте отображёны иконки сотрудников

  Сценарий: сокрытие фильтра "Сотрудники"
    Пусть выбран фильтр "Сотрудники"
    Если нажимаю на кнопку "закрыть фильтр"
    Тогда окно фильтра "Сотрудники" скрыто
```

Оба эти сценария работают по отдельности, имплементация этих шагов достаточно широкая, да и не особо имеет смысл, наверное, её здесь выводить, скажу только одно, заканчивается запуск данных сценариев вместе такой вот марахайкой:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.mts.m2m.b2b.stepDefinition.FilterDefinition.selectFilter(FilterDefinition.java:31)
    at ru.mts.m2m.b2b.stepDefinition.FilterDefinition.выбран_фильтр(FilterDefinition.java:71)
    at ✽.Пусть выбран фильтр "Сотрудники"(.\Feature\Filter.feature:23)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.mts.m2m.b2b.stepDefinition.FilterDefinition.selectFilter(FilterDefinition.java:31)
    at ru.mts.m2m.b2b.stepDefinition.FilterDefinition.выбран_фильтр(FilterDefinition.java:71)
    at ✽.Пусть выбран фильтр "Сотрудники"(.\Feature\Filter.feature:23)
```

Чем может быть вызвано такое? Где посмотреть в первую очередь?

Comment: смотрите в `FilterDefinition.java` в строке 31

Comment: Да, прошу прощения за торопливость изложения, но это первое куда я посмотрел. К сожалению, это не разъяснило ситуацию

Comment: приложите этот код к вопросу

Comment: Блин, пока писал код, нашёл почему NullPointer. Оказывается, definition файлы при новом сценарии заново инициализируются, поэтому, некоторые класс просто равнялись null

Comment: В принципе в хорошем сценарии должно быть всего одна пара when/then. И делать несколько таких пар - в корне не правильно.